# (Google Tag Manager) GTM enhanced ecommerce checkout steps not tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I've implemented GTM on an ecommerce site and have some tags set up for a few thins (page impressions, add to cart etc.) These all work and track in Analytics as expected however I've now added the checkout funnel pushes and these are firing but not tracking.

Data flow is basically:
User Visits Cart Page >> Step 1 dataLayer.push request >> Console shows Checkout Tag has fired >> Data doesn't show up in analytics.

An example of this dataLayer push event is as follows:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'checkout',
    'ecommerce' : {
        'currencyCode' : 'GBP',
        'checkout' : {
            'actionField' : {'step' : 1},
            'products' : [
            {
                'name' : '&quot;Some product name&quot;',
                'id' : '55',
                'price' : '35',
                'quantity' : 1
            }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

It looks like the problem is more likely a setup issue with GTM so I've included the current settings I have for the Checkout Tag:

```
Tag Type - Universal Analytics
Tracking ID - {{ Tracking-ID }}
Track Type - Event
Category - Ecommerce
Action - Checkout
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features - True
Use data layer - True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error deleting the tag from GTM and re-adding it solves the issue.

I'm not really sure why this is. It's also worth noting if using the dataLayer.push() method included on page load (rather than attached to an action) it can fire before GTM is ready which may lose data. Instead wrap it in a $(document).ready (if you're using jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

### String vs Integer

Quantity is an Integer type, you have string type.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#ecommerce-data

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'checkout',
    'ecommerce' : {
        'currencyCode' : 'GBP',
        'checkout' : {
            'actionField' : {'step' : 1},
            'products' : [
            {
                'name' : '&quot;Some product name&quot;',
                'id' : '55',
                'price' : '35',
                'quantity' : 1
            }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jakub,

I spotted this this morning too and changed it to an INT, didn't make any difference though but if you or anyone else spots anything small like this I'll switch it out and give it a go. If this was the problem I would've though the GTM preview debugger would've thrown an error but it showed ok. I've updated the question.

Comment: That is strange, your call looks correctly. Do you have correct trigger? event equals checkout? Can you add debugger info? Can you add what is sended to google-anayltics? mean google.analytics.com/collect?v=1....

Comment: I've uploaded screenshots of the debugger here: http://imgur.com/a/nPn20 It's the easiest way to show it but I have stripped out any specific information that links to my account

Answer (score 0):

The following works absolutely fine for me, may be try adding 'option' with your step

```
dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'checkout',
                'ecommerce': {
                  'checkout': {
                    'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Billing Address'},
                    'products': [{
                      'name': 'Sony VAIO',
                      'id': 'VGN-TXN27N/B',
                      'price': '2494.22',
                      'category': 'Peripherals',
                      'quantity': '1'
                      }]

                 }
               },
               'eventCallback': function() {
                  //document.location = 'checkout.html';
               }
              });
```

Here is the GTM settings

[image: GTM Setting 1]

[image: GTM Setting 2]